# Knife delete node nodename not working

Tags: chef-infra

I'm running chef 12 on ubuntu 14.04 with an 10.8.5 OSX workstation. When I run

```
knife node delete 'nodename'
```

I get prompted and confirmed that the node deleted. When I run a

```
knife client list
```

the deleted node shows up. If I try to poke it or delete , it says node not found. Any thoughts

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between [nodes](http://docs.chef.io/nodes.html) and [clients](http://docs.chef.io/knife_client.html). While the first one, is an instance managed by chef, the latter one is an instance that has access to the chef-server API.

To achieve what you want (to remove a machine provisioned by chef client), you need to issue the following two commands:

```
knife node delete 'nodename'
knife client delete 'nodename'
```